# Lost phone : is Ubuntu One login linked to SIM card?

Tags: ubuntu-one, login, sync, phone, data-loss

I recently lost my phone and I'm now trying to reset all logins I could have configured before a mess starts. Some of them are protected since the login is linked to the SIM card (for instance google) : if the SIM is replaced, the login is not valid any more.

What about Ubuntu One login ? Does it work if the SIM is replaced ?

If the answer is no, then it's great.

If the answer if yes, it's even great since I could remotely delete pictures on my phone through U1 and then change the login.

Any answer will suit me, but I need to know what strategy to adopt.

thx

Comment: Is the SIM PIN protected? If not your google account can still compromised using wifi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ubuntu One mobile clients do not store your password on the phone: rather they store an [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) access token that is used to authenticate as you to the Ubuntu One services.  This is stored on the phone's memory rather than the SIM, so you should probably consider it compromised the same as if it was on the SIM.

You can cancel this access token through the Ubuntu One web site at the following URL in the `Devices` section:

https://one.ubuntu.com/account

Once you get a new phone, you should be able to sign in to the Ubuntu One client the same way you did on your previous phone and generate a new OAuth access token.

Comment: So if the OAuth access token is kept, then deletion of my data on my ubuntu one account should have deleted content on my lost phone (as soon as the guy try to update my u1 app which is unlikely). Am I wrong ?

Comment: If you downloaded any content locally to your phone, that will probably still be there on the SIM card.  The phone would no longer be able to access or modify anything in the cloud though.

Answer (score 3):

You can manage which devices have access to your Ubuntu One account. Simply go into your account settings and delete the stolen phone.